# What is the APNS message structure to receive message with AWS Amplify iOS so the onNotification event is properly triggered?

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint, aws-amplify

I setup PushNotification.onNotification from @aws-amplify/pushnotification like so:

```
      if (notification.foreground) {
        console.log('notification received in foreground ', notification);
      } else {
        console.log('notification received in background ', notification);
      }

      if (PushNotificationIOS !== undefined) {
        notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
      }
    });
```

On Android it's working fine. On iOS I can't trigger the onNotification/onNotificationOpened events, although I receive the notifications. There is a special case when I send the "Standard Message" via Pinpoint -> Test Messaging, which actually triggers the function, and when I log the notification it looks like this

```
'notification received in background ', 
{ _data: 
{ remote: true,
notificationId: '45BAA2A6-8676-402E-8E6B-03A69173AC8C' },
_remoteNotificationCompleteCallbackCalled: false,
_isRemote: true,
_notificationId: '45BAA2A6-8676-402E-8E6B-03A69173AC8C',
_alert: { title: ' test', body: 'qwerty' },
_sound: undefined,
_badgeCount: undefined,
_category: undefined,
_contentAvailable: 1,
_threadID: undefined }
```

(the notification was received in the foreground, but the message doesn't contain that info, so it prints as background. Both foreground/background will trigger the event when using **Pintpoint -> Test messaging -> Standard message**). Also Pinpoint Raw message does not work. SNS Identical / custom payload does not work.

I have augmented AppDelegate as according to
https://github.com/react-native-push-notification-ios/push-notification-ios#augment-appdelegate

Anybody knows if amplify expects a certain payload in order to trigger the event? Or if something else could be causing this..?

### Structures tested so far:

The SNS custom structure

```
  "APNS_SANDBOX": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Sample message for iOS development endpoints\"}}"
}
```

Pinpoint raw message

```
{
    "APNSMessage": {
        "aps": {
            "alert": ""
        }
    },
    "GCMMessage": {
        "data": {
            "message": ""
        }
    },
    "ADMMessage": {
        "data" : {
            "message": ""
        }
    },
    "BaiduMessage": {
        "title":"",
        "description": ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add content-available and additional data to access the title, body and data in iOS of amplify PushNotification.

```
{
  aps: {
    alert: {
      title: "title",
      body: "message"
    },
    "content-available": "1",
    key1: "value",
    key2: "value",
  },
}
```

Stringified

```
"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":{\"title\":\"title\",\"body\":\"message\"},\"content-available\":\"1\",\"key1\":\"value\",\"key2\":\"value\"}}"
```